# How to give a closure an argument with lifetime that ends right after call to closure?

Tags: rust, closures, lifetime, borrow-checker

I want to call a closure with type `Fn(usize, Option<&'a Response>) -> bool + Send + 'static + Sync` like so `should_retry(number_of_retry, Some(&response))` and then immediately after I want to take ownership of the response. But currently I can't because the closure is free to store the reference (if I understand correctly). How can I encode in the closure type that the lifetime of the `Option<&'a Response>` should be immediately discarded?

Should I instead give ownership of the `Response` to the closure while forcing it to return the `Response` right after, like so: `Fn(usize, Option<Response>) -> (bool, Option<Response>) + Send + 'static + Sync` ? Is there another way to do this with lifetimes?
The problem with the above is that I need to trust the caller to actually return me the Response back.

[Link to playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=57dbcf0e75ca7540eeec12dc59acbc93)

Comment: If the lifetime is based on `&'a Response` just bind the return type to that lifetime too, so it means that for that closure, what you get and what you return should have the sale lifetime.

Comment: What do you mean by `bind the return type to that lifetime`? I tried replacing `+ 'static` with `+ 'a` but that didn't work.

Comment: can you provide an example?

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/JakubKoralewski/c0f7e316db77567bd9d748c8b20de9e1)'s a snippet (lines 61-66 is where the thing im referencing here happens)

Comment: @korai, please take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I included a link to the playground.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was in the `'a` lifetime on the function containing the call to the closure. Where before it was:

```rs
fn send_with_retry_cond<'a, RC: Fn(usize, Option<&'a Response>) -> bool + Send + 'static + Sync> {
```

Removing the `'a` lifetime parameter and replacing it with `'_` fixed it:

```rs
fn send_with_retry_cond<RC: Fn(usize, Option<&'_ Response>) -> bool + Send + 'static + Sync> {
```

I think the issue is that a generic lifetime parameter (let's call it `'a`) defined on a function requires that `'a` lives as long as the function body. Which was not the case here, as I needed `'a` to end right after the call to the closure (which of course is part of the body).